# How optimally to query a dataframe for some large set of keys

Tags: pandas

#### Problem Statement

I have a large (e.g. 2GB) dataframe indexed by short strings (e.g. `FAM227A`, `PVT1`, `TAT`). It represents a database.

I also have a list of short "query" stings.

I'd like to compute some statistics on the slice of the dataframe defined by my list of query strings. Essentially, I'd like to query the "database" and then do some statistics. I'm wondering what the *pandas* way of doing this is. I can think up a couple ways:

- `database.merge(query, how='right', left_index=true, right_on=0)`
- something involving [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) like `database.loc[query]`
- something involving [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)
- something else?

My requirements are that I want this to be maximally fast, ideally not copy the data (i.e. return a view), and particular to my case is the fact that the my queries will often be for > 90% of the keys in the DB.

#### Example data

```
db = pd.DataFrame(['FAM227A', 'PVT1', 'TAT'], columns=['name']).set_index('name')
q = ['FAM227A']
# ... your query operation here ... 
# ... returns a dataframe with the info from DB about the keys from query
```

Comment: Well it will be hard to know for sure if something is 'the *best*', especially when you provide an example dataset with only 3 rows...  FWIW, I would just start with `loc` and see how far that gets you.  That would be the default approach IMO (and generally pretty fast).  Also not sure about returning a view (I guess you could save an index though?).  A lot of this will depend on your workflow, which you don't really specifiy

Comment: @JohnE how might the approach differ based on the workflow? In my case, I'll be doing a `groupby` another column on the results and then a hypergeometric test. Right now, i'm using postgres+sqlalchemy but some queries take as much as 4-5s. The absolute fastest way to do this in pandas probably doesn't depend on my workflow, right?

Comment: I mean, it sounds like you need a subset of the data.  Are you then doing multiple operations on that same subset?  Or do you take repeated subsets and do a single operation on each subset?  I think there are going to be different answers for those two questions.  And I think you'll get better answers if you provide a larger sample dataframe and more details on exactly how you are processing it.  That's the only way to test the answers and find which is best.

Comment: @JohnE thanks for explaining. I'll be frequently grabbing large subsets and doing a single operation, as part of an API for a web service. Does that change your answer.